# PokerStars Android - Cards History

Tags: hud, poker-stars

I'm a professional software developer and usually play on my android phone. Unfortunately there seems to be no HUD software for the pokerstars app on android. As a result, I plan on creating such an app myself.
I already contacted the poker stars support and my request has be forwarded to the ideas team.
In the meantime, I thought it might be a good idea to ask around, if someone else made approaches in this direction.
I have a few questions and would appreciate any help.

1. I was unable to find existing solutions for  HUD apps for the pokerstars app on android. Do HUD apps for pokerstars and android already exist?
2. On the windows OS the card history is located in the users local temp folder. Does such a location exist for the android app?
3. Has someone of you already made experiences with the poker stars idea team? How likely is it, that pokerstars will actually help me in my approach to create an HUD app? I understand that there might be no gain for pokerstars by doing that.
4. Is there a way to access to ingame-data without trying to interpret the data displayed on the screen?

Regards Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Point wise answer

1. [Here](https://www.cardschat.com/f61/android-mobile-live-hud-free-beta-207855/) is a beta for andriod HUD
2. I don't think HH is stored on the phone anymore. If you make an HUD it will have to determine actions literally by looking at the action
3. Pokerstars will point you to the list of allowed features in an HUD but not much more. once it is ready they will ask for a demo copy of the software to see it does not violate their allowed software policy. They will as a policy not provide you with any technical help or API access though and even if you manage to hack/hook an API they will swiftly ban accounts using your software as it is against their policy. only human readable data is allowed to be used, meaning what you see on the screen and what may be stored on the users device.
4. Refer point 2.